# Magnitude of \$I_{CBO}\$ in a typical transistor

Tags: transistors, diodes, thermal, saturation, common-collector

I read in a book that \$I_{CBO}\$ doubles for every 10 degree rise in temperature and hence contributes to thermal runaway. However I am confused since essentially it is the reverse saturation current through Base-collector junction while Emitter-Base junction is open circuited, so it should be something in μA and even if it rises 10 folds , it will still be negligible compared to other curremt changing factors so I tried to search for magnitude of this current to resolve my confusion however i was unable to find it on internet. So kindly provide the data.

Comment: Use `\$` for inline MathJAX on EE.SE (and use the preview before posting!).

Comment: Whta is wrong with this expressions : $\mu$ and $I_CBO$ ?

Comment: They should be `\$ \mu \$` and `\$ I_{CBO} \$`.

Comment: You can also use HTML `&Omega;`, `&mu;`, `&deg;`, etc. as well as `<sup>...</sup>` and `<sub>...</sub>` in the posts but they don't work in the comments. Again, use the preview before posting. I can see you posting several times a minute at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a real application there is typically voltage between emitter and collector, so the \$I_{CBO}\$ current can effectively be base current and thus be multiplied by the gain and cause a lot of dissipation.

"Is" in the SPICE model for a given part will give you a sort of "typical" value for that particular part at room temperature. It is usually in the nA range at room temperature.

Comment: But do we really care about \$I_{CBO}\$ when we are using BJT's in modern applications?

Comment: Got it but still can you please tell me the magnitude at room temperature ? Because I want to have a idea of the magnitude.

Comment: Yes, you care about it, but a resistor from emitter to base can deal with it in may cases.

Comment: The maximum possible values for \$I_{CBO}\$ can be found here https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/P2N2222A-D.PDF for a small signal BJT's. The typical value will be one order of magnitude smaller.

Comment: It's typically in the nA range. This is more of a concern for Darlingtons, Sziklai pairs and similar DC coupled transistors where the junction temperature is very high **and** the gain is very high. Is in the SPICE model will give you a guess for Icbo.

Answer (score 1):

This is leakage current, from the CB junction being stressed near avalanche breakdown.